# How to print Pdf via Wifi/Bleutooth printer?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, printing, itext

I want to print Pdf file via Wifi/Bleutooth printer but before that i want to connect to the printer

I have tried a methode to do that but the problem is my printer dimensions are small than Pdf page size (A4)

How do I make the file compatible with all sizes of printers?

Here is some code :

```kotlin
        private fun savePdf(
            invoiceType: String,
            invoiceModel: SalesDatabase,
            date: String,
            personType: String,
            personName: String,
            paymentMethod: String
        ) {

            val am: AssetManager = context.assets
            var font: PdfFont?
            try {
                am.open("text.ttf").use { inStream ->
                    val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    var nRead: Int
                    val data = ByteArray(16384)
                    while (inStream.read(data, 0, data.size).also { nRead = it } != -1) {
                        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead)
                    }
                    font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(buffer.toByteArray(), PdfEncodings.UTF8)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return
            }

            val mFileName = SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
            val mFilePath =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
                    .toString() + "/" + "$invoiceType Invoice" + mFileName + ".pdf"
            val file = File(mFilePath)
            file.createNewFile()
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(outputStream)
            val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
            val mDoc = Document(pdfDocument)
            try {
                if (file.exists()) {

                    //Setting
                    mDoc.pdfDocument.defaultPageSize = PageSize.A4

                    val typeInvoice = "Invoice $invoiceType"
                    val text =
                        Paragraph(typeInvoice).setBold().setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                            .setFont(font).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(22f)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)

                    val textWidth = PageSize.A4.width
                    val table1 = Table(FloatArray(1) { textWidth })
                    table1.addCell(
                        Cell().add(text)
                            .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    )

                    mDoc.add(table1)

                    addLineSpace(mDoc)

                    val width = PageSize.A4.width / 3
                    val columns = FloatArray(3)
                    columns[0] = width
                    columns[1] = width
                    columns[2] = width
                    val infoTable = Table(columns)
                    val theDate =
                        Paragraph("Date : $date").setBold().setFont(font)
                            .setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(12f)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    val theTypeName =
                        Paragraph("$personType Name: $personName").setBold().setFont(font)
                            .setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(12f)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    val thePaymentType =
                        Paragraph("Payment method : $paymentMethod").setBold().setFont(font)
                            .setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(12f)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)

                    infoTable.addCell(
                        Cell().add(theDate)
                            .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    )
                    infoTable.addCell(
                        Cell().add(theTypeName)
                            .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    )
                    infoTable.addCell(
                        Cell().add(thePaymentType)
                            .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    )

                    mDoc.add(infoTable)

                    addLineSpace(mDoc)
                    addLineSeparator(mDoc)
                    addLineSpace(mDoc)

                    addTable(mDoc, invoiceModel, font)
                }

                mDoc.close()

                showPleaseWaitDialog(false, "")
                Toast.makeText(context, "تم إنشاء الملف", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Toast.makeText(context, "تم حفظ الملف في $mFilePath", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                Handler().postDelayed({
//                    val intent = Intent(context, ShowPdf::class.java)
//                    intent.putExtra("pdfUrl", mFilePath)
//                    context.startActivity(intent)

                    printPDF(file)
                }, 1000)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

```kotlin
        private fun printPDF(file: File) {
            if (OptionDatabase.isWifiMode(context)) {
                val printManager: PrintManager? =
                    getSystemService(context, PrintManager::class.java)
                try {
                    val printDocumentAdapter: PrintDocumentAdapter =
                        PdfDocumentAdapter(context, file.path)
                    printManager!!.print(
                        "Document",
                        printDocumentAdapter,
                        PrintAttributes.Builder().build()
                    )
                } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Can't read pdf file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return
            }
            if (OptionDatabase.isBluetoothMode(context)) {
                Printooth.printer().printingCallback = this
                Printooth.printer().print(pdfToBitmap(file))
                return
            }
        }
```

```kotlin
        private fun pdfToBitmap(pdfFile: File): ArrayList<Printable> {
            val bitmaps = ArrayList<Printable>()
            try {
                val renderer = PdfRenderer(
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
                        pdfFile,
                        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY
                    )
                )
                var bitmap: Bitmap
                val pageCount = renderer.pageCount
                for (i in 0 until pageCount) {
                    val page = renderer.openPage(i)
                    val width: Int =
                        resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / 72 * page.width
                    val height: Int =
                        resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / 72 * page.height
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                    page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
                    bitmaps.add(ImagePrintable.Builder(bitmap).build())

                    // close the page
                    page.close()
                }

                // close the renderer
                renderer.close()
            } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
                context.showToast(ex.message.toString(), 0)
            }
            return bitmaps
        }
```

```kotlin
        private fun addTable(document: Document, invoiceModel: PurchaseDatabase, font: PdfFont?) {

            val columns = FloatArray(5)
            columns[0] = 30f
            columns[1] = (PageSize.A4.width - 30f) / 4
            columns[2] = (PageSize.A4.width - 30f) / 4
            columns[3] = (PageSize.A4.width - 30f) / 4
            columns[4] = (PageSize.A4.width - 30f) / 4

            val table = Table(columns).setMarginBottom(20f)

            addCell(table, "", font!!, true)
            addCell(table, "Product Name", font, true)
            addCell(table, "Price", font, true)
            addCell(table, "Quantity", font, true)
            addCell(table, "Total", font, true)

            val myType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductBuyModel>>() {}.type
            val products =
                Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<ProductBuyModel>>(invoiceModel.products, myType)

            for (s in products.indices) {
                addCell(table, (s + 1).toString(), font, false)
                addCell(table, products[s].productName, font, false)
                val price =
                    (products[s].productPrixTotal - products[s].productTax) / products[s].productQuantity
                addCell(table, price.toString(), font, false)
                addCell(table, products[s].productQuantity.toString(), font, false)
                addCell(table, products[s].productPrixTotal.toString(), font, false)
            }

            addCell(table, "", font, false)
            addCell(table, "", font, false)
            addCell(table, "Payment : ${invoiceModel.paymentPrice}", font, true)
            addCell(table, "Rest : ${invoiceModel.restPrice}", font, true)
            addCell(table, "Total : ${invoiceModel.totalPrice}", font, true)

            table.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE)
            table.isKeepTogether = true
            document.add(table)
        }
```

When I tried my code, the result was like this:
[image: Result of my code]

[image: Printer Information]

Comment: how i can apply this solution on my code? (I use iTextPdf library)

Comment: how i can know which format the printer supported??...Currently I am converting pdf pages to images than I print them (but you see the result above)

Comment: my question here is why the printer doesn't print what pdf has...why print "vvvvvvvvvv..."?

Comment: How can I contact you to solve this problem first and then talk about the cause of the problem
Because the client is waiting for me to hand over the project to him

Comment: I will upload an image that contains all information of the printer

Answer (score 1):

What type of printer are you using? Printing to these smaller mobile printers connected to Android can be a little trickier than printing with Windows print drivers.

Depending upon the model, this printer will have a native language (Zebra has Zebra Print Language aka ZPL and is one of the most popular). Usually you would not print a raw PDF but send the print data embedded in the ZPL / native printer language. While this sounds complicated, it does make some things easier (Especially when barcodes are needed).[Zebra Print Language Info FYI](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/ZPL-Command-Information-and-DetailsV2?language=en_US#:%7E:text=Zebra%20Programming%20Language%20%28ZPL%29%20is%20the%20command%20language,examples%20and%20specific%20information%20related%20to%20ZPL%20Commands.)

Sizing universally might be a little tough since most of the printers index in dots (Absolute) and utilize different fonts/sizes. I guess it could be done BUT I've not seen it yet.

Connecting is pretty simple in both cases. You could simply ping for the IP printer then open a socket and send the print stream such. For Bluetooth you could open a Bluetooth socket then close it thus finding out if it is present and online. The code below which assumes you have a printer list and their addresses (IP or Bluetooth).
NOTE: The below should be encapsulated in an AsyncTask doinbackground method and assumes that your raw print data is in the params[1](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/ZPL-Command-Information-and-DetailsV2?language=en_US#:%7E:text=Zebra%20Programming%20Language%20%28ZPL%29%20is%20the%20command%20language,examples%20and%20specific%20information%20related%20to%20ZPL%20Commands.) element. Also, the below is Java BUT the Kotlin conversion should be pretty simple!

```
            //region BT
            if (is_bluetooth()){


                try{
                    status = "Printing";
                    if (bt_dev == null){
                        bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        bt_dev = bta.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    }
                    bt_socket = bt_dev.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    bt_socket.connect();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not create BT Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground: ", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not create BT Socket";
                }


                try{
                    os = bt_socket.getOutputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not connect BT Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground: ", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not connect BT Socket";
                }


                try{
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException  ex){
                    errs.add("OutputStream Delay Problem:" + ex.getMessage());
                }


                buff = params[1].getBytes();
                for (c = 0; c < buff.length; c++){
                    try{
                        //Thread.sleep(2);
                        os.write(buff[c]);
                    }
                    catch (IOException  ex){
                        errs.add("OutputStream Delay Problem:" + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }



                try{
                    os.close();

                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not close BT Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground: ", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not close BT Socket";
                }
            }
            //endregion

            //region IP
            if (is_ethernet()){
                try{
                    status = "Printing";
                    prn_addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                    sock = new Socket(prn_addr, port);

                }
                catch (UnknownHostException ex){
                    errs.add("Unknown Host Error!");
                    Log.e("DCCERR Unknown Host", "doInBackground:IPPrint", ex);
                    return "!" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("I/O Error!");
                    Log.e("ERR IO Error", "doInBackground:IPPrint", ex);
                    return "!" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    errs.add("Gen Error!");
                    Log.e("ERR IO Error", "doInBackground:IPPrint", ex);
                    return "!" + ex.getMessage();
                }

                try{
                    os = sock.getOutputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not connect IP Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground:IPPrint ", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not connect IP Socket";
                }

                try{
                    buff = params[1].getBytes();
                    os.write(buff);
                    os.flush();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not write to IP Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground:IPPrint ", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not write to IP Socket";
                }


                try{
                    os.close();

                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    errs.add("Could not close IP Socket");
                    Log.e("ERR", "doInBackground:IPPrint", ex);
                    status = "Ready";
                    return "!Could not close IP Socket";
                }
            }
        }
```

Connecting in the Bluetooth world is a little more involved but still rather simple. Simply setup an intent/broadcast receiver match so that you can start the discovery process and select a BT device. This also gives you the options of selecting a paired device OR actually pairing with a new device! Something like the below:

```
    //region INIT_BT
public boolean init(){
    try{

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        con.registerReceiver(bt_interface, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        con.registerReceiver(bt_interface, filter);

        //REGISTER TO GET MESSAGES FOR BT DISCOVERY STARTED
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        con.registerReceiver(bt_interface, filter);

        //GET THE DEFAULT ADAPTER
        bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //TURN BT ON
        if (!bta.isEnabled()){
            log("init_bt", "Turned BT On", null);
            bta.enable();
        }

        //INIT DEVS AND DEVLIST ARRAYLISTS
        devs = new ArrayList<String>();
        dev_list = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

        //GOOD IF WE MADE IT HERE
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        log("init_bt", "Init Failure", ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now for a few gotchyas:
The mobile device / app / printer combinations can cause a few timing issues which we have seen over the years. You may need to induce a small char delay as you are sending BUT this depends on the mobile device/app/printer combo. If you get no response when trying to print then try to add a small char delay (5ms/10ms)

The above code certainly is not the only way to do this and I'm sure there are some optimizations we could add BUT this has worked on multiple mobile device manufacturers and mobile printer manufacturers for years!

There's more to it than can be explained in one post BUT this should hopefully at least give you a direction!